# IDL file - static linking or dynamic linking

Tags: c++, visual-c++, static-linking, dynamic-linking, idl

I want to use the function interface **"IApplicationActivationManager"** & it's member functions "**IApplicationActivationManager::ActivateApplication**"
 [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706903(v=vs.85).aspx)

It's present in Shobjidl.h & Shobjidl.idl.
I've seen *.DLL or *.lib as the dependency where the Microsoft functions are defined, so we know wheather it's static linking or dynamci linking.

> But I'm trying to understand what does IDL do - dunamic or static
>   lining ? DO I need to provide any DLL/lib ? How does the lining happen ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IApplicationActivationManager is a COM interface type.  COM objects are always created dynamically at runtime, they don't have a linking requirement beyond ole32.lib, possibly a .lib that defines the GUID for the object.  You obtain the interface pointer with the universal COM object factory, CoCreateInstance().

A sample probably helps, I'll post the code for a Win32 console mode app that activates the weather app on Windows 8.  Create the project from the provided VS project template.  No changes required, the template already links everything that's needed (kernel32.lib, ole32.lib and uuid.lib).

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <ShlObj.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main()
{
    auto hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
    assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));
    IApplicationActivationManager* itf;
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ApplicationActivationManager, NULL, 
                          CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER,
                          __uuidof(IApplicationActivationManager),
                          (void**)&itf);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        auto weatherApp = L"Microsoft.BingWeather_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App";
        DWORD dontuse;
        hr = itf->ActivateApplication(weatherApp,
                                      L"", AO_NONE, &dontuse);
        assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));
        itf->Release();
    }
    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

You need the application user model ID for the app that you want to activate, [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn449300%28v=winembedded.82%29.aspx) describes how to discover them.

Comment: Thank you. It helps. I want to display a image *.png, *.jpg etc.. using "Photos metro application" from my console app & I want to ONLY use facilities in "mincore.lib" & nothing outside it.  I don't think kernel32.lib, ole32.lib etc..  is presemnt in mincore.lib ? I'm exploring how can i achieve this? Also in the 2nd argument of ActivateApplication() if I provide the  image name"abc.png" will it display. ?

Comment: Mincore.lib is fine, you should have been able to discover that by yourself.  You cannot just pass "abc.png", the full path name is required.  Like c:\foo\bar\abc.png.

Comment: I'm giving it something like this :: 
LPCWSTR imageArg = L" C:\\data\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Muscles-Posterior.png";

hr = paam->ActivateApplication(appId, imageArg, AO_NONE, &pid);

But it's just opening the photos application but not opening the image "PNG" file ?

Comment: @codeLover I don't think with the current version of Visual c++ it's possible to only link against mincore.lib, the CRT startup code links against a few functions in kernel32.lib that aren't in mincore.lib